# How to keep user logged in react-native using aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I have already done getting the user from aws cognito and how can I do it properly to keep the user logged in even when the react native app is closed

```
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false
  }

  authenticate(isAuthenticated) {
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated })
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log('Auth: ', Auth)
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Hello {Auth.user.username}!</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Tabs
          screenProps={{
            authenticate: this.authenticate.bind(this)
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Auth API provided from Amplify, once you use Auth.signIn, that API will manage your session state.

In your main entry component (probably App.js) check in the componentDidMount() method what Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() will return before and after you've signed in with a valid user.

```
... // standard imports
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsmobile from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsmobile);

class App extends Component {
   state = { isLoggedIn: false }
   ...
   async componentDidMount() {
     try {
       const authedUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
       console.log(authedUser) // this means that you've logged in before with valid user/pass. 
       this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
     } catch(err) {
       console.log(err) // this means there is no currently authenticated user
     }
   }

   render() {
     if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
       return <Homescreen /> // or whatever your entry component is
     }
     else {
       return <Login />
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: also personal opinion, you can wrap your entry component in a Higher Order Component (HOC) that will manage all this auth stuff in the the HOC and only render your main entry component if your logged in. Kind of out of the scope of this question but I recommend taking a look

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncStorage---------

```
state = {
    isAuthenticated: false
  }

componentWillMount(){
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Mylogin:key');
  if (value !== null){
    this.setState({
    isAuthenticated: true
    }) 
  } 
}

  authenticate(isAuthenticated) {
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated });
    AsyncStorage.setItem('@Mylogin:key', 'Loggedin');
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log('Auth: ', Auth)
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Hello {Auth.user.username}!</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Tabs
          screenProps={{
            authenticate: this.authenticate.bind(this)
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to configure or import await Asyncstorage to react native? also what is @Mylogin:key is this supposed to be my token returned from auth?

Comment: (Q) Do I need to configure or import await Asyncstorage to react native?
(A)Yes

(Q) also what is @Mylogin:key is this suppose to be my token returned from auth?
(A) It can be any key you can use your auth token in it.
basically idea  is that the a key is stored in the app in form of asyncstorage. So when user is logged in set this key so when ever app launches it will check that key is present or not if its available  mark user as logged in else user will asked for login(If app goes in background and comes in foreground then also this will work)Whn you want to log out just remove the key

Comment: what happens now is value returns not null, but in {auth.user.username} it is saying username undefined .. should I also store the user ?

Comment: yes, you can save the username also in another key. And pass it when required.